# undefined reference to `sqlcxt'

Tags: c, linux, gcc

Trying to compile some C code (a simple `select * from dual` with oracle (11g) db connection on Linux, generated from .pc thru `proc` command) through the `gcc` command and I always get an error.

```
undefined reference to 'sqlcxt'
```

I tried to link to libraries I saw on different forums around the web, but got nothing (error still occurs):

```
gcc -o proc_test proc_test.c -L$ORACLE_HOME/lib/libclntsh.so
```

and I still get

```
/tmp/ccAW4Imj.o: In function `main':
proc_test.c:(.text+0x3ea): undefined reference to `sqlcxt'
proc_test.c:(.text+0x57c): undefined reference to `sqlcxt'
proc_test.c:(.text+0x60d): undefined reference to `sqlcxt'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Can anyone help with that?

Comment: `-L` is for adding a library search path... `-l` for an actual library.

Comment: gcc -o proc_test proc_test.c -l$ORACLE_HOME/lib/libclntsh.so

/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -l/opt/oracle/products/11g/client/lib/libclntsh.so
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

but there is such a library in that path...

Comment: Did you try `-L$ORACLE_HOME/lib -lclntsh`?

Comment: yeap:

gcc -o proc_test proc_test.c -L$ORACLE_HOME/lib -lclntsh
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /opt/oracle/products/11g/client/lib/libclntsh.so when searching for -lclntsh
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lclntsh
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: Is it possible you're compiling for 64-bit and trying to link to a 32-bit library, or vice versa?

Comment: i added -m32 and it compiled ! thanks a lot! now i'll try to connect to db )

Comment: @KabanCityStar You may post an answer yourself and accept it if it worked for you.

Comment: A Google search for 'oracle sqlcxt library' shows quite a lot of places where the information can be found.

Comment: but no one google search adviced to put -m32 to gcc, so i solved my problem only after Dmitri proposed to do that

Answer (score 6):

The answer is:

```
gcc -o proc_test proc_test.c -L$ORACLE_HOME/lib -lclntsh -m32
```

I just needed to put `-m32` cause libs and linux have different bits